# Extract float number from a list based on range

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm trying to extract float numbers (seconds) from a list (list1) based on a range generated from float numbers in a a second list. The first list looks like this:

```
list1 = [12.5, 15.3, 17.8, 20.4, 21.3, 24.5, 26.5, 28.3, 30.4, 33.5, 36.7]
```

The second list (list2) looks like this:

```
list2 = [20.4, 26.5, 33.5]
```

For every item in list2 I want to retrieve the items of list 1 within 3 seconds.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Am I correct in saying that for every item in list 2 you want to retrieve the items of list 1 within 3 seconds?

Comment: that is correct. Just realized is not very clear this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `np.searchsorted` to find the required indices into `list1`. As the name suggests this requires `list1` to be sorted:

```
idx = np.searchsorted(list1,np.add.outer(list2,(-3,3)))
[list1[l:r] for l,r in idx.tolist()]
# [[17.8, 20.4, 21.3], [24.5, 26.5, 28.3]]
```

Comment: the code is working only if I have 2 numbers in list 2. how can I use it if I have more than two numbers?

Comment: @Giuseppe Oops, sorry, I had the order of the arguments to `add.outer` mixed up. They need to be swapped. Should work now.

Answer (score 2):

You can store your values in dictionary in order to reach them higher speed, and may use try-except block to test if value is in your array/list.

Example with your values:

```py
#Inputs
list1 = [12.5, 15.3, 17.8, 20.4, 21.3, 24.5, 26.5, 28.3, 30.4, 33.5, 36.7]
list2 = [20.4, 26.5, 33.5]

#To get value faster 0(1) time complexity use dictionary
list1_dict = (dict( zip( list1, list1)))

#Loop for each value in list2
for v in list2:
    try:
        value = list1_dict[v]
    except:
        value = None
    if value != None:
        print("{} value found in list1".format(value))
    else:
        print("{} value NOT found in list1".format(value))
```

Output:

> {17.8: 17.8, 20.4: 20.4, 21.3: 21.3, 36.7: 36.7, 33.5: 33.5, 24.5: 24.5, 28.3: 28.3, 26.5: 26.5, 12.5: 12.5, 30.4: 30. 4, 15.3: 15.3}
>   20.4 value found in list1
>   26.5 value found in list1
>   33.5 value found in list1

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas
list1 = pandas.Series([12.5, 15.3, 17.8, 20.4, 21.3, 24.5, 26.5, 28.3, 30.4, 33.5, 36.7])
list2 = [20.4, 26.5]
print(list1[list1.between(*list2)])
```

will do what you want i think...

(Im not sure i exactly understood your question though...)

Comment: Thank you Joran. I don't need numbers in between, even tough I may use this somewhere in the final code. I'm struggling to extract float numbers from a list using range of int numbers. the number I'm looking in list1 have to be the same of the numbers in list2. I don't like working with lists ;)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what you want the final output to look like. I will assume you want a list of lists, where the nth list contains all the elements of `list1` that are within 3 seconds of the nth item in `list2`. You can adjust this to create other structures if needed.

Here's a simple version that is probably quick enough unless `list1` is very long:

```
list1 = [12.5, 15.3, 17.8, 20.4, 21.3, 24.5, 26.5, 28.3, 30.4, 33.5, 36.7]
list2 = [20.4, 26.5, 33.5]
list3 = [
    [x for x in list1 if abs(x-y) <= 3] 
    for y in list2
]
print(list3)
# [[17.8, 20.4, 21.3], [24.5, 26.5, 28.3], [33.5]]
```

Since `list1` is sorted, you can search it quickly using the bisection algorithm. This will be much faster if `list1` is very long:

```
import bisect

def get_matches(val, lst):
    """ Return list of items in lst that are within 3.0 of val. """
    left = bisect.bisect_left(lst, val - 3.0)
    right = bisect.bisect_right(lst, val + 3.0)
    return lst[left:right]

list3 = [get_matches(x, list1) for x in list2]
print(list3)
# [[17.8, 20.4, 21.3], [24.5, 26.5, 28.3], [33.5]]
```